# How to upload video to youtube without authorizing every time?

Tags: video, go, oauth, youtube, authorization

In my use case, I would like to upload video to my youtube channel in Golang. I am referring to this [api](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/go/upload_video.go) sample. When I upload the video, youtube asks for authorization[authorization window opens and asks for manual approval]. Most of the time code sample uses cache. But I am afraid that oauth authorization may affect video upload through application. Could anyone give some suggestion how can I handle this?